# Swift 3 Equatable Struct optional function

Tags: swift

This will be a little long winded so please bear with me. I am also a bit of a swift beginner as well. I have an array with a defined struct.

```
var modelOriginalArray                      = [model]()

struct model: Equatable  {
    var modelID         = String()
    var modelName       = String()
    var modelNumber     = String()
    var manufacturer    = String()
    var manufShort      = String()
    var phiTypeCode     = String()
    var phiTypeDesc     = String()


    init(modelID: String, modelName: String, modelNumber: String, manufacturer: String, manufShort: String, phiTypeCode: String, phiTypeDesc: String) {
        self.modelID        = modelID
        self.modelName      = modelName
        self.modelNumber    = modelNumber
        self.manufacturer   = manufacturer
        self.manufShort     = manufShort
        self.phiTypeCode    = phiTypeCode
        self.phiTypeDesc    = phiTypeDesc
    }

    static func == (lhs: model, rhs: model) -> Bool {
        return lhs.manufShort == rhs.manufShort && lhs.modelName == rhs.modelName && lhs.modelNumber == rhs.modelNumber
    }


}
```

I load about 5000 records into this array.  I then have a need to filter this array based on search criteria.  Let's say I am looking for a manufacturer "Sony".  There is the possibility of multiple models for Sony so I need to separate all Sony records from the greater 5000.

```
    srchval = "SONY"
    var filteredArray = [model]()
    var uniqueFilteredArray = [model]()

    filteredArray = self.modelOriginalArray.filter { $0.manufShort.range(of: srchval, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

This will give me an array with only "Sony" records. However there is a possibility that some of those "Sony" records have duplicate **manufShort**, **modelName**, **modelNumber** values under different **modelID's**. I need to separate those and only have unique records.

```
    // Find Uniquic options by removing duplicate Model Names
    uniqueFilteredArray = unique(models: filteredArray)


func unique(models: [model]) -> [model] {

    var uniqueModels = [model]()

    for model in models {
        if !uniqueModels.contains(model) {
            uniqueModels.append(model)
        }
    }

    return uniqueModels
}
```

This all works ver well. The problem I have is in the filter there are situations where I have to make sure the record is matching on:

```
    static func == (lhs: model, rhs: model) -> Bool {
        return lhs.manufShort == rhs.manufShort && lhs.modelName == rhs.modelName && lhs.modelNumber == rhs.modelNumber
    }
```

And in a different situation in the same class I need to match only on the **manufShort**:

```
    static func == (lhs: model2, rhs: model2) -> Bool {
        return lhs.manufShort == rhs.manufShort
    }
```

I have tried creating a separate model i.e.. model2 with this different static function, but I have difficulties moving data from one array to another with a different struct.

Any thoughts or a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Since you use two different approaches for defining the "equality" of two models, you should probably consider not using the `==` operator, as you don't really test equality if the equality predicate is different from case to case. Rather, you have two different custom predicates (which applies to two model instances) that you would like to use in different contexts. Why not use two custom type (static) methods for this, with descriptive names, semantically describing their different meanings?

Comment: @dfri Thanks! That makes a great deal of sense, how do I call the different (static) methods so that it will hit the right function based on what I am after.  An example?

Comment: Sure, I added an example (`Foo` rather than `Model`, in the sense of example :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use two different approaches for defining the "equality" of two models, you should probably consider not using the `==` operator, as you don't really test equality if the equality predicate is different from case to case. Rather, you have two different custom predicates (which applies to two model instances) that you would like to use in different contexts. Why not use two custom type (static) methods for this, with descriptive names, semantically describing their different meanings?

> Thanks! That makes a great deal of sense, how do I call the different (static) methods so that it will hit the right function based on what I am after. An example?

Example setup:

```
struct Foo {
    let id: String
    let bar: Int
    let baz: Int
    let bax: Int
    init(_ id: String, _ bar: Int, _ baz: Int, _ bax: Int)
    {
        self.id = id
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz
        self.bax = bax
    }

    static func byBarEqualityPredicate(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.bar == rhs.bar 
    }

    static func byBazAndBaxEqualityPredicate(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.baz == rhs.baz && lhs.bax == rhs.bax 
    }
}

let fooArr = [Foo("Foo A", 1, 2, 3),
              Foo("Foo B", 1, 1, 2),
              Foo("Foo C", 3, 1, 2)]
```

A slightly modified version of your `unique` method, now supplying a `(Foo, Foo) -> Bool` predicate among with the `foos` array:

```
func unique(foos: [Foo], predicate: (Foo, Foo) -> Bool) -> [Foo] {
    var uniqueFoos = [Foo]()
    for foo in foos {
        if !uniqueFoos.contains(where: { predicate($0, foo) }) {
            uniqueFoos.append(foo)
        }
    }
    return uniqueFoos
}
```

Testing with the two different `Foo` predicates:

```
// by 'bar' "equality": Foo A and Foo B will be considered "equal",
// and only Foo A, among these two , will be added to the "unique" array.
let fooWithBarPredicate = unique(foos: fooArr, predicate: Foo.byBarEqualityPredicate)
fooWithBarPredicate.forEach { print($0.id) } // Foo A, Foo C

// by 'baz' && 'bax' "equality": Foo A and Foo C will be considered "equal",
// and only Foo A, among these two, will be added to the "unique" array.
let fooWithBazBaxPredicate = unique(foos: fooArr, predicate: Foo.byBazAndBaxEqualityPredicate)
fooWithBazBaxPredicate.forEach { print($0.id) } // Foo A, Foo B
```

Comment: This worked quite well for me.  I was even able to add a third predicate for a more focused search.  Perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following extension on `Collection`. Not tested.

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    func uniques(by equals: (Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var uniqueElems: [Iterator.Element] = []
        for elem in self {
            if uniqueElems.index(where: { equals($0, elem) }) == nil {
                uniqueElems.append(elem)
            }
        }
        return uniqueElems
    }   
}
```

Then you can use

```
filteredArray.uniques { $0.manufShort == $1.manufShort }
filteredArray.uniques { $0.manufShort == $1.manufShort && $0.modelName == $1.modelName && $0.modelNumber == $1.modelNumber }
```